# How to match a specific tag for a given volume in AWS with boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

What I'd like to do is check to see if a volume contains a certain tag, ie `is_managed`.  If the volume has the tag, skip over it, otherwise add the tag to the volume.

```
volumes = conn.get_all_volumes()
tags = conn.get_all_tags()

for volume in volumes:
  for tag in tags:
    if tag.name.startswith('is_managed'):
      pass
    else:
      volume.add_tag('is_managed', True)
```

This code works (kind of), but it will iterate over all tags, even if they don't match the criteria I am searching for.  So it ends up adding the `is_managed` tag but it incorrectly calculates the number of tags to match, plus is it really slow.

**How can I look at a single tag to see if it matches the criteria I am looking for?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting all the tags for conn by calling this: tags = conn.get_all_tags() 
What you want is to get all the tags of the current volume, so you want to do something like:

```
volumes = conn.get_all_volumes()
for volume in volumes:
    if not 'is_managed' in volume.tags:
      volume.add_tag('is_managed', True)
```